# Why does escaping greater than or less than work in bash string comparisons?

Tags: bash

If I try something like

```sh
if [ a < b ]
```

in bash it interprets it as trying to pipe one file to another. If I want to do a string comparison I know I should escape the operator like this:

```sh
if [ a \< b ]
```

I know I could use [[ to get around this but my question is, why does escaping like this work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In essence, `[` is a program that does what you want when its arguments are `a`, `<`, `b`, and `]`. (In fact, Bash implements `[` as a builtin, but it implements it *as if* it were a separate program, rather than treating it specially. This is for compatibility with systems where `[` is literally a separate program on the path.)

So, just as writing `echo a \< b` or `echo a '<' b` or `echo a "<" b` lets you call `echo` with the arguments `a`, `<`, and `b` (so as to print `a < b`), writing `[ a \< b ]` or `[ a '<' b ]` or `[ a "<" b ]` lets you call `[` with the arguments `a`, `<`, `b`, and `]` (so as to test whether `a` is less than `b`).

Answer (score 5):

`[` is an ordinary command, so if you *don't* escape it, it is parsed as a command with 2 arguments, `a` and `]`. The `< b` is processed as an input redirection and removed from the command line before `[` is executed. That is, `[ a < b ]` and `[ a ] < b` are equivalent.

`<` is not a standard operator supported by `[`; `bash`'s implementation allows for such comparisons, but if you are relying on one non-standard extension, you may as well rely on `[[` instead.

Comment: I don't understand the question. It *does* produce an error.

Answer (score 2):

If you escape a character in bash your basically telling bash to pass the escaped character "as it is" to the underlying command.

In your case (if-statement) the part in the brackets is passed to the "test" command: https://ss64.com/bash/test.html

If you don't escape, the "<" operator, it is **first** interpreted by bash and **afterwards** the result of this interpretation (`a < b`) is pased to the test command.

Comment: If you don't escape `<`, then `[` never sees `<` or `b`; they are consumed as an input redirection and not included in the argument list for `[`.